# quickfix: How to know whether a fid is in a group or not?

Tags: quickfix

Let's assume there is such part in quickfix's data dictionary

```
    <message name="Name" msgtype="type">
      <field name="field1" required="Y"/>
      <field name="field2" required="Y"/>
      <field name="field3" required="N"/>
      <group name="group1" required="Y">
        <field name="field4" required="Y"/>
      </group>
      <group name="group2" required="Y">
        <field name="field5" required="Y"/>
        <field name="field6" required="N"/>
      </group>
    </message>
```

While sending request, I need to construct message correctly - set field5 in group2, field4 in group1, and field1 outside of any group. Is there a way in quickfix library to know, for example, if field4 is in a group or not? And in which group?

If not, how is it possible to use quickfix library, if you are depending on data dictionary client will use? I should force clients to configure data dictionary as I configured it?

Answer (score 1):

> I should force clients to configure data dictionary as I configured it?

Yes.  A server ("acceptor") and its clients ("initiators") should all be using the same DataDictionary.

If you are providing a server, you should provide documentation that defines exactly what messages/fields you support, and how use use those messages and fields.  If you don't provide a QuickFIX data dictionary file, you should provide sufficient information so that client firms can create one.

> Is there a way in quickfix library to know, for example, if field4 is in a group or not? And in which group?

I think you are asking this question because you don't really know what you're doing yet.  :)

I *think* there might be DD methods for this, but I can't really remember because they're not something people usually need.  I don't think this is the right approach for whatever your problem is.

Comment: You need to create/edit the DD xml file so that it matches your counterparty's definitions.  Whatever you're wanting to do with DD methods is simply not the right way to go.